# Wikipedia first paragraph

Tags: java, parsing, web-scraping, jsoup, wikipedia

I'm writing some Java code in order to realize NLP tasks upon texts using Wikipedia. How can I use JSoup to extract the first paragraph of a Wikipedia article?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 8):

It is very simple, and the process is quite similar for every semi-structured page from which you are extracting information.

First, you have to uniquely identify the **DOM element** where the required information lies in. The easiest way to do this is to use a web development tool, such as [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) in Firefox, or the ones that come bundled with IE (> 6, I think) and Chrome.

Using the article **[Potato](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potato)** as an example, you will find that the `<p>`aragraph you are interested in is in the following *block*:

```
<div class="mw-content-ltr" lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <div class="metadata topicon" id="protected-icon" style="display: none; right: 55px;">[...]</div>
  <div class="dablink">[...]</div>
  <div class="dablink">[...]</div>
  <div>[...]</div>
  <p>The potato [...]</p>
  <p>[...]</p>
  <p>[...]</p>
```

In other words, you want to find the first `<p>` element that is inside the `div` with a `class` called `mw-content-ltr`.

Then, you just need to select that element with jsoup, using its selector syntax for example (which is very similar to jQuery's):

```
public class WikipediaParser {
  private final String baseUrl; 

  public WikipediaParser(String lang) {
    this.baseUrl = String.format("http://%s.wikipedia.org/wiki/", lang);
  }

  public String fetchFirstParagraph(String article) throws IOException {
    String url = baseUrl + article;
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    Elements paragraphs = doc.select(".mw-content-ltr p");

    Element firstParagraph = paragraphs.first();
    return firstParagraph.text();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    WikipediaParser parser = new WikipediaParser("en");
    String firstParagraph = parser.fetchFirstParagraph("Potato");
    System.out.println(firstParagraph); // prints "The potato is a starchy [...]."
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello again, thank u very much indeed. The proposed solution works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the first paragraph is also the first `<p>` block in the document. So this might work:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree").get();
Elements paragraphs = doc.select("p");
Element firstParagraph = paragraphs.first();
```

Now you can get the content of this element

Comment: The `getElementsByClass()` returns elements by class name, not by tag name.

Answer (score 1):

The solution proposed by Silva works for most cases except like in "[JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript)" and "[United States](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States)". Paragraphs should be selected as doc.select(".mw-body-content p");

Check [this GitHub](https://github.com/tejzeratul/WikiText/blob/master/src/com/tejzeratul/Fetch.java) code for more details. You can also remove some metadata information from HTML to improve accuracy.